# Delete a record from index page

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to ember and trying to build a very simple app as a learning exercise in 2.4. I have a list of tasks that appear on the index page. And I've attached actions to each one to delete. And have one form row on the bottom of the page with an action to saveTask.

I have one index controller.
No defined index routes.
One model for tasks at app/models/task.js

My function to saveTask is working. But I can't get the deleteTask to work. I know I'm not passing the object I want to delete correctly. The error returned is that `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.js:26
deleteTask`.

Can someone explain the correct syntax to me?

```
 app/templates/index.hbs
{{#each model as |task| }}
    <div class="form-horizontal form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
            {{input type="text" value=task.taskname class="form-control"}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
            {{input type="text" value=task.startdate class="form-control"}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
            {{input type="text" value=task.enddate class="form-control"}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
            {{input type="text" value=task.duration class="form-control"}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
            {{input type="text" value=task.banding class="form-control"}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" aria-label="Remove task" {{action 'deleteTask' task}}>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

and the controller

```
app/controllers/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {

        deleteTask(task) {
        this.destroyRecord();
        this.transitionTo('index');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `this` in your context is the controller and the controller doesn't have a `destroyRecord` method, what record are you trying to delete? Is it the current model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `destroyRecord` in `deleteTask` on `this` not on the `task`, which is actually the record. I think that's all.

You should be able to see in developer tools the line in code which throws. I bet it's `this.destroyRecord();`.

Comment: When I change it to task, the error changes to `Mirage: Your Ember app tried to DELETE '/tasks/2', but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route that matches this path in your mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace? `  What connector am I missing?

Comment: You did not define a route for `tasks` and `delete` method in mirage. It's just an issue with mocking your api. Have a look at [mirage documentation](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/). For further issues please open up another question since it's does not seem to be related.